# JPA Specification equivalent of ResultTransformer.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, distinct

I was wondering if there's an equivalent of ResultTransformer.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY to use in JPA Specifications? Right now, I'm trying to implement search functionality and I must use JPA Specifications for that (I'm not allowed to use CriteriaQuery or other alternatives).

I have to execute a JOIN in the search query because there's a one to many relationship between entities.

So, right now, I'm doing this:

```
String type = "admin";
SpecificationBuilder sb = SpecificationBuilder.getInstance();
Specification<WebContentImpl> spec = new Specification<WebContentImpl>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<WebContentImpl> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.equal(root.join("users", JoinType.LEFT).get("type"), type);
    }
};
sb.addSpecification(spec);
```

As you can see, I can include a JOIN. Several users are mapped to a single web content item. However, when there are for example 3 users mapped to 1 web content item, the web content item should only be shown 1 time, but it's shown 3 times. I had this problem in the past, and the flag ResultTransformer.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY helped me out then, but I can't use that functionality now.

Sure, I can implement my own solution to leave out the doubles, but it will be terrible for the performance. And I already tried changing the JoinType, but the result was always the same.

Anyone out there with some tips to help me? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
K

Comment: @braok I have the same question, did you get an answer or work around?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [distinct(boolean) in CriteriaQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#distinct%28boolean%29).

Comment: actually this generates the expected result  but as a result query will contains `distinct` clause which has performance considerations.

Answer (score 1):

You can de-duplicate via `group by` based on primary key column of root table:

```
cq.groupBy(root.get("id"));
```

Assuming that `WebContentImpl.is` is primary key column of that table.